# Calendar in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for an alternative way to handle date and daterange input than the preset function.

In particular, I am not happy with the fact that the calendar is shown only when the user click on the date/daterange to modify the value. I would like a "fixed" calendar.

Any suggestion?

Comment: would it work for you if it the dateRangeinput is by default expanded?

Comment: @BigDataScientist That would be a possible workaround.

Comment: Best would be a default expanded version of daterangepicker http://www.daterangepicker.com/